# Loop through IDs and inserting if not exists and updating if exists

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, t-sql, querying

I have an issue I need to resolve. I have two tables, one of them contains ID's of individual employees. The second table contains ID's of those employees and certain values. My task is to insert rows into the second table for each employee ID if they don't exist and update the value if they do exist. This is where I am starting but not sure how to proceed. Specifically, how to import the values of each ID or iterate through them.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [procedure name]  
    @employeeID INT  
AS  
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;  
BEGIN  
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 
                   WHERE testEmployeeID  = @employeeID AND testCode = 'someValue')  
        INSERT INTO dbo.table2 (testCode, testEmployeeID, 'testValue')  
        VALUES ('someValue', @employeeID, 'someValue2')
    ELSE 
        -- (update the values) 
END
```

Comment: Why do you want to loop/iterate? That is the *slowest* way to achieve this.

Comment: Also why are you changing the isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED` when you want to do an `INSERT`? That's a *terrible* idea.

Comment: This is easiest with 2 queries. 1 query to update, a second to insert. To check if a record is present you can either use an EXISTS clause with sub query or an OUTER JOIN with NULL check. I recommend you do not change the default isolation level and use READ COMMITTED which is usually the default.

Comment: Easiest is the use of a MERGE statement

Comment: Thank you guys. Apologies, I am very new at SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two tables then a simple MERGE statement suffices.
Like:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.table2 AS TGT
  USING ( SELECT testCode, testEmployeeID, testValue FROM dbo.table1
  ) AS SRC
    ON  SRC.testCode = TGT.testCode
    AND SRC.testEmployeeID = TGT.testEmployeeID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET testValue = SRC.testValue
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT( testCode, testEmployeeID, testValue )
  VALUES( SRC.testCode, SRC.testEmployeeID, SRC.testValue )
;
```

If however the original comes at transactional level one row after the other then again a MERGE statement suffices as well. However in this case you need to construct your "record" in line directly or with a temporary table before the merge.

```
MERGE INTO dbo.table2 AS TGT
  USING ( SELECT 'someValue' AS testCode, @employeeID AS testEmployeeID, 'otherValue' AS testValue
  ) AS SRC
    ON  SRC.testCode = TGT.testCode
    AND SRC.testEmployeeID = TGT.testEmployeeID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET testValue = SRC.testValue
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT( testCode, testEmployeeID, testValue )
  VALUES( SRC.testCode, SRC.testEmployeeID, SRC.testValue )
;
```

Performance wise the first option to compare two tables is better.

Comment: MERGE INTO dbo.table2 AS TGT
  USING ( SELECT table1ID FROM dbo.table1
  ) AS SRC
    ON  SRC.table1ID= TGT.table2EmpID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE 
  SET table2Value = 'value2'
  --WHERE table2value1= 'value1'
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT( table2value1, table2EmpID, table2Value )
  VALUES( 'value1', src.table1ID , 'value2' );
After doing this (without the where statement) all table2values get updated while I only need the value that matches the where clause to be replaced or inserted. However when I put the where statement, the function breaks. Not sure what is wrong her

Comment: THank you everyone. Especially Knut. I tried your way, in the first post. However I am getting some issues. Not sure if it's a syntax error or something else. Thank you!

Comment: @brunas - Based on your comment, I think you want something like `...WHEN MATCHED AND table2value1= 'value1' THEN...`.

Comment: @benThul Thanks. I tried it, doesn't cause an error but it also doesnt change any rows for some reason.

Comment: Do you for sure have rows that match? Like if you do `select TGT.* from dbo.table2 as TGT join dbo.table1 as SRC on SRC.table1ID = TGT.table2EmpID where TGT.table2value1= 'value1'`, does it return rows?

Comment: So after further inspecting, this function does change the values in the rows which already exist. The problem is that if the rows don't exist, it doesn't add those rows for all employee ID's.. @BenThul

Comment: Looking at your statement, I can't see how that'd be the case. The only thing I'd suggest is validating that claim with `select table1.ID from dbo.table1 as a left join dbo.table2 as b on a.ID = b.ID where b.ID is null`. Also, it's not wrong, in your merge, you can just say `using dbo.table1 as SRC`. That is, you don't need to do a subselect there.